# Binary Tree - Which kind of binary tree

Tags: binary-tree

Which kind of binary tree that each node is greater that left child and less than right child?

a. Complete tree
b. Binary Search Tree
c. Threaded Tree
d. Full binary Tree

Answer (score 0):

b. Binary Search Tree
read this if you have time[BST](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~gildea/csc282/slides/C12-bst.pdf)